# PHPMailer SMTP Class not found

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I have followed the tutorials line by line and not sure why im am getting this error. My php mailer code is as follows.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/private/PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php";
require dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/private/PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php";    
require dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])."/private/PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php";

// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                     
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->Host       = 'a2plcp473.prod.iad.secureserver.net';          
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                  
    $mail->Username   = 'ew@myemail.com';                     
    $mail->Password   = 'xxx';                            
    $mail->SMTPSecure =  'tls' ;                                
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                   

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('ew@mymail.com', 'Name');
    $mail->addAddress('ew@othermail.com', 'Name');     
    $mail->addReplyTo('ew@othermail.com', 'Name');

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

I know my file paths are correct because i put a echo "This" in each file and it's echoing back out to the screen. So the paths are correct.

The error im getting is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SMTP' not found in 
/home/xxx/public_html/public/internal/mail.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
/home/xxx/public_html/public/internal/mail.php on line 23
```

Line 23 is:

```
$mail->isSMTP();
```

Im stuck here. I have been searching online for solutions for two days now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. I also know there is other post like this on stack but i have tried all of those and can't get it to work. Likewise, most of them are for people using composer and i am not using composer, im just including the file path. Also most of them use and autoloader which was deprecated recently. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion:  learn to use composer. It will make your life much easier. The old PHPMailer autoloader was deprecated 3 years ago, not recently.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `use` statement to bring the SMTP class into your namespace. Add this alongside the others:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

Comment: Once i add that, i get another message: 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.

Comment: ...which means that it's working perfectly! That's just the mail server's not-very-friendly way of saying hello, it's not any kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

Please check [Installation & loading](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#user-content-installation--loading):

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

> If you're not using the SMTP class explicitly (you're probably not),
>   you don't need a use line for the SMTP class.

However, you are using SMTP class explicitly:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;    
                   ^^^^
```

You need to either refer to `SMTP` with the fully-qualified name (`PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP`) or alias it with `use`.

---

If it's finally working and you don't want to see debug messages, remove or comment this line:

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
```

The [default](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v6.1.6/src/PHPMailer.php#L401) is `SMTP::DEBUG_OFF`.

Comment: So i would add "use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP" to the top with the other use lines? Then keep the "$mail->SMTPDebug" line the same?

Comment: Yes, one thing or the other. You could do both but it'd be redundant.

Comment: Once i add that, i get another message: 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.

Comment: Since you're getting a response from the mail server that means your code is finally running. I've added a note on how to turn debugging off.

Answer (score 0):

The solution it's here to fix the error on the line $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER; https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2360

Comment: please add the necessary details to make your answer useful even if the link becomes invalid in the future.